# Should a space faring species interfere in a Mass-extinction event, which is necessary for the evolution of a future civilization?

Tags: evolution, civilization, interspecies-relations, extinction, ethics

I recently came across an audiobook called Permian by Devyn Regueira.  The synopsis was about a recent discovery of fossilized eggs and two strange cave carvings in Siberia, one that describes the genome of a proto-mammalian species, the other maps of stars as they would appear over the ages.  As an avid sci-fi fan, I immediately knew the story such a discovery told.

250 million years ago, there was a sapient species advanced enough to understand genetics and see the Permian mass extinction coming, but not advanced enough to take action to stop it, or flee their dying homeworld.  So, out of options, they set up a way for a future civilization to bring them back and give them a second chance.  And while I was thinking of a question about what a space-faring humanity's official policy on interference with less advanced species should be (I want to come back to that one), one part of that question about what to do for primitive civilizations facing extinction level events, combined with the synopsis of the book showed itself to be more interesting in its ramifications.

So let’s suppose for a moment that there was a sapient species of Proto-mammals living on earth advanced enough to understand genetics and primitive rocketry, at the time an alien exploration vessel was patrolling the system. The vessel in question is from a species with close diplomatic ties to humanity that have found themselves thrown back in time. (Science experiment gone wrong; happens all the time)

Near as we can tell, the “Great Dying” as it is sometimes called, was started with a massive eruption in Siberia that set off a biblical chain reaction, methane hydrate was released from beneath the sea, the atmosphere warmed, the oceans boiled and turned to acid, the land dried and turned to deserts, dogs and cats were living together, all that good stuff.

So suppose the science officer of the ship comes to the Captain with a plan that might save this species from extinction.  Let’s say the plan might work and the Proto-mammalian civilization could be spared.  Herein lies the problem.

If this rescue attempt succeeds, the millions of years of history that would give rise to the dinosaurs and eventually us, have now been thrown on their head.  Even if our distant ancestors were left unmolested and allowed to eventually evolve into us (the odds of that happening standing at slim to none), the Proto-mammals would have a 250 million year technological head start when humans begin banging rocks together.  And even if the Proto-mammals were taken off world and given a new home, what’s to stop them from recolonizing the earth after the Great Dying is over and their former homeworld has recovered?  Hell, what’s to stop them from colonizing their rescuers' homeworld hundreds of millions of years before they even learned how to walk?  250 million years is a long time, and even if you tell them about the future and make them swear to not interfere in prehistory, there is no guarantee that their decedents won’t get tired of waiting and just claim the galaxy as theirs and theirs alone, especially since they now know that interstellar travel and time travel are possible.

So now the captain of the ship now faces a Trolley Problem.  Let nature take its course and leave a sapient race to their horrific fate, or try to save them and face the possibility that home might not be there if and when they return?

So here is the million credit question: **Should a Space Fairing Species Interfere in a Mass-Extinction Event Necessary for the Evolution of a Future Civilization?**

Comment: That rather depends very strongly on how time travel works in your story, doesn't it? How many timelines are there? Meddling with the past will change **a** future: but will it change **the** future? And if meddling in the past changes **the** future, does this imply that when the time tavellers try to meddle they will vanish in a pooof! of smoke because the future they came from no longer exists and thus they don't exist also?

Comment: The issue being how do you know weather or not it’s your future your changing?  Your might not know until it’s too late.

Comment: This rather sounds like a character motivation and it's a story dependent reason. I am not sure it's a generic world building one. If you [don't already have guidelines for your routine time travelling](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/162648/time-travelers-paradox-prevention-guidelines) then how are we to say how this particular commander would act?

Comment: See Star Trek's Prime Directive (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime Directive)

Comment: I am aware of the Prime Directive, in fact the flaws in its later use of it in letting civilizations die horrible preventable deaths was one of the reasons why I wanted to ask about what our interference policy should be in the future.  This question here examines the “you don’t know the consequences will be” argument, in a case where you have some idea of what the consequences will be.  The possible non-existence of a long term ally or the certain extinction of a sentient species, it was one situation that gave me pause when I’m usually on the side saying, “SAVE THEM, YOU IDIOTS!”

Comment: By the way, that wiki link leads to a Prime Numbers page, not the Prime Directive page.

Comment: Bring to proto-mammles to the present day and give them a planet.

Comment: No................

Comment: Rather than answer the question "Should they" (which is totally opinion based and going to get closed by the mods) - I think a more interesting question is "why should or shouldn't they". I'm of the opinion of saving their lives - if we simplify it down to a trolley-problem-like thought problem it's a no brainer "If you flick the switch to stop the train they'll know you exist, if you don't they all die." Plus saving someone's life is a good opening intro.

Comment: It's a paradox and a morality question. However, one problem with the paradox is that *250 million* years is a phenomenally long time that might mitigate paradox. Maybe the Protos wiped themselves out in a nuclear war 249.99 million years ago. Or maybe they moved to orbital habitats and left Earth 249.95 million years ago. The problem with a morality question is that morals depend upon both brain structure and culture, neither of which we know. Both the aliens and the Protos may have quite different moral codes *that work just fine for them*. "Save them or not?" seems Anthropomorphized.

Comment: This is an ethics question and character or plot question, not worldbuilding.

Comment: Okay here is a serious question, if anything ethical is opinion based and automatically closed, why does this site bother with an “ethics” tag?

Comment: For building an ethics system in a fictional world. Your question is "should this character do this?" not "how do I make this the ethical choice in this scenario?" or "what conditions would make this the ethical choice for my species?" or such.

Answer (score 1):

**Screw 'em, Probably**

Proto-mammals already dead in this timeline?  The saving of which would kill off the actual real-to-me people that are my allies and trillions of their fellows? Not even a hard question.  They must Die so others may Live.  or....

Maybe not.  Time travel is wild man.  And human knowledge of events 250 million years ago are sketchy-at-best.  For example, we THINK an asteroid impact killed the dinosaurs, but there's also tons of evidence indicating they were doomed already and the asteroid was more "disturbing a corpse" than "ending a thriving line of beings." This is almost 200 million years even further back. We can only guess at what went on.  Maybe your humans have no records of events, or nobody with enough paleontology to remember what actually happened.  Probably nobody knows the truth anyway.  Then it's your classic "save a primitive race" problem.  Maybe The Great Dying wasn't a random chain-reaction at all.  Maybe it was these proto-mammals immolating themselves in some sort of WWIII scenario.  So maybe, because Time Travel is weird, you "saving" them now is what CAUSES humans to evolve the way they do.  Because if you let THIS kill them, instead of Proto-mammal WWIII a hundred years from now, humans never evolve.
or....

Maybe you try to split the baby.  You save some proto-mammals on the sly, to preserve the species.  Let the rest go extinct "the natural way" and pray the 500 or 5,000 or 5 million or however many you recovered weren't somehow critical to humanity's evolution.  You take them somewhere far away, dump them on THAT planet, and do what you can to ensure the things forget they were ever anywhere else.  Maybe you only beam aboard children, maybe you mind-wipe adults, it's up to you!  You know these guys won't make it anyway, because your future-humans have no records of them, but hey at least you tried right?
or....

Maybe your future-humans-thrown-into-the-past DO have a record of these guys.  Well, not EXACTLY these guys.  But some wildly advanced race halfway across the galaxy that astral projects (their words, because any sufficiently advanced science looks like magic to the uninformed anyway) bodies that look sort of like these proto-mammals, and they have a myth about being "placed upon our Holy World" by the gods long ago.  Are they the same species? Does that mean you SHOULD try to bring some proto-mammals onboard and move them to where you think the future god-race's homeworld is?  To preserve the timeline?  Or maybe you're mistaken, and doing that will actually mess with the god-race's evolution and ruin everything! Or, or or....

There's a ton of other problems you could come across.  But it boils down to how well the humans (or the guy in charge of making the call) know what's "supposed" to happen.  In the end though you're probably "safest" letting the suckers die, because that act is the "least invasive" answer.